# Best practices for using GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS in gitlab CI/CD

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gitlab, terraform, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to make GitLab pipelines that deploy GCP instances through the [GCP terraform provider](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/index.html).  Other platforms like AWS have environmental variables like `$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` that can be used to authenticate requests, but GCP seems to use service account credential files instead.

I could create a CI gitlab file variable to contain my GCP service account credential file, but I can only add it in an insecure way.  If I attempt to mask my file variable under the GitLab ci-cd settings it produces the error message `This variable can not be masked.`

What is the proper best practice for storing GCP service account credential files in GitLab CI/CD environmental variables?

Comment: Where is Gitlab running? If in GCP, you can use a default service account assigned to the instance and not have secrets in your pipeline.

Comment: You can Gitlab runner in your GCP VM or GKE. Assign the service account with required rights to your VM. Installation of Gitlab runner in GCP can be found here: https://about.gitlab.com/solutions/google-cloud-platform/

Comment: Other than the above solutions, you will have to keep your SA key file in a secure place that can be accessed by ur pipelines using creds saved securely on ur CI.
then fetch the SA key file and then use it to perform the required operation.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to take the environment variable and write it out as a file. When you add variable in the newer versions of Gitlab, there is a dropdown that lets you choose between "Variable" and "File". If you put the contents in the value field, you can use a `cp $VARIABLE_NAME name-of-file.bob`.

You don't need to mask it because it is never written to the log (unless you cat it), but I do recommend you check the "Protect" check box which means it will only be used on protected branches.

A second approach is to encrypt it and decrypt it using a password which is in a protected variable. It would require getting another program in the build, but that might work for you.

A third is use something like [age](https://github.com/FiloSottile/age) to check in the encrypted file, write out a SSH as a fancy decryption key, and then package the SSH.

But, the first approach is probably going to be your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

**Best practice in terms of security:**

1. You need to generate a JSON key file containing the credentials that
   GitLab will use to authenticate Google Cloud.
2. In Gitlab -> `Settings` -> `CI/CD` expand `Secret variables` area
3. Here goes your GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS as a key and additionally with the value the content of step 1
4. Refer to your key value pair in the configuration file in your pipeline

For example like this in your pipeline configuration file (step 4):

```
variables:
  GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS: $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
```